# 301/302 error using ajax to send mail

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a Laravel application where one can apply for a quotation. This gets done by an Ajax call. So far no problem. Then I want to notify the website owner with an email. I tried a lot of different things, but I can't get it working.

Here is the ajax call when the user submits the form

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'quotation',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: input,
    success: function(data){
        if(data == "success"){
            sendmail(input);
        }
)};
```

the quotation url validates the input and returns if this is done correctly or not.

Here is my `sendmail` function, which gets called when the form is successfully filled in

```
function sendmail(input){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'mail',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: input,
            complete: function(xmlHttp){
                console.log(xmlHttp.status);
            }
        });
    }
```

The mail function is as follows

```
public function postMail(){
        $input = Input::all();

        Mail::send('_emails.quotation', $input, function($message) {
            $message->to('xxx@gmail. com', 'xxx')->subject('Offerte aanvraag');
        });

        return Redirect::to('quotation');
    }
```

The response I get in my console is the following:

```
XHR Loaded (quotation - 200 OK - 305.8150000870228ms - 679B)
XHR Loaded (mail - 302 Found - 291.1389999790117ms - 703B)
XHR Loaded (kristal - 301 Moved Permanently - 2.579999971203506ms - 285B)
XHR Loaded (kristal - 302 Found - 206.71699999365956ms - 709B)
XHR Loaded (home - 200 OK - 247.7790000848472ms - 13.254KB)
```

I don't really get what is going on..

Comment: 301/302 are not errors - they are normal http responses. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301 & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302

Comment: I think it is worth mentioning that this is bad design. The way you have it set up anyone can decide to send mails at any time, which is just begging for exploits.

Comment: yeah, I know, I just made a function to check where the error was coming from..